# MSW: Failed to register a ServiceWorker for scope with script The script has an unsupported MIME type ('text/html')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, github-pages, msw

I am working on a react app using MSW. Everything was cool until I deployed my app to Github pages.

This is an error I get:

**Uncaught (in promise) Error: [MSW] Failed to register a Service Worker for scope ('https://myprofile.github.io/') with script ('https://myprofile.github.io/mockServiceWorker.js'): Service Worker script does not exist at the given path.**

homepage in package.json:

http://myprofile.github.io/reponame/

Answer (score 1):

You need to only `start` the `worker` if the code is running in development environment.

Wherever you're starting the `worker` (*probably in `index.js` file*), add the following check:

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "development") {
  const { worker } = require("./mocks/browser");
  worker.start();
}
```